# Forced enterprise enrollment

Tags: operating-systems, chromebook, acer

Recently picked up an Acer Chromebook 14. Have tried to unsuccessfully wipe it using the esc arrow power trick, but it always instantly re-enrolls me into enterprise enrollment. Dev mode is blocked by admin as well. Any tips?

Comment: You have to go the prior owner to un-enroll it.

Comment: Yes.  That is the only way.